# Site page publishing button gets disabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

im having issue with pagers Publishing feature Sharepoint 2010. 
issue is Publishing button is  not enable in the ribbon?

[image]

my site was migrated form 2007 to 2010 im assuming todo that ? 
this are the features that active with relevant the page publishing.
1.Publishing Prerequisites 
2.Publishing Resources 
3.SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure.

also i checked my Reusable content list  from SPD below how's looks .
[image]

appriceate your help ..

Comment: What are your permissions on the library? What happens if you Submit first?

Comment: i have SPfarm admin permissions..

Comment: You may be the farm admin, but that does not mean that you have publishing permissions on the site. So, what permissions do you have on the site and the library?

Comment: hi i have the approvers group permission with full controll to library.

Comment: OK. What happens if you submit first? C'mon, I'm trying to help but this is like pulling teeth.